# Get part of the email/string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have the following input which needs parsing:

```
<?php
$from = "Johnny Smith <johnnyc@gmail.com>";
$to = "5005@adresss.com";
```

I would need the following output

```
 $name = "Johnny Smith" // just the name
 $email = "johnnyc@gmail.com" // just full email
 $node = "5005" //remove @address.com or 2nd part of any other email address
```

Is there any simple solutions to clean and split the strings - especially the $from variable, with reasonable reliability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `php` functions: [strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
$from = "Johnny Smith <johnnyc@gmail.com>";
$to = "5005@adresss.com";

$name = trim(substr($from, 0, strrpos($from, '<'))); 
$email =  substr(strrchr($from, '<'), 1, -1);
$node = strstr($to, '@', true); 

var_dump($name, $email, $node);
```

Comment: Seems to work... However, What if the name actually contains "<" ? Is it possible to start from the right side instead of left so then only the first < is caught?

Comment: @dfhdfh changed my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, will test it

Comment: @dfhdfh great, np

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Will also work if local part (name) contains a '<'. See comments for step-by-step explanation. Outputs:

```
string(12) "Johnny Smith"
string(17) "johnnyc@gmail.com"
string(4) "5005"
```

Code:

```
<?php

$from = "Johnny Smith <johnnyc@gmail.com>";
$to = "5005@adresss.com";

/*
Regexp explanation (from regex101.com):
1st Capturing Group (.*?)
.*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
< matches the character < literally (case sensitive)
2nd Capturing Group (.+)
.+ matches any character (except for line terminators)
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> matches the character > literally (case sensitive)
*/
preg_match_all('/^(.*?)\s<(.+)>$/', $from, $matches);

// First capture group is in $matches[1]
$name = $matches[1][0];

// Second capture group is in $matches[2]
$email = $matches[2][0];

// Split on @ and grab the local part.
$node = explode('@', $to)[0];

var_dump($name); // string(12) "Johnny Smith"
var_dump($email); // string(17) "johnnyc@gmail.com"
var_dump($node); // string(4) "5005"
```

Comment: Thanks... What's the advantage compared to the previous answer?

Comment: While that isn't a bad solution per se, it's a little more complicated than it needs to be. Simplicity is one of the things to always strive for. Compare their 6 function calls to my 2. Simplicity and performance typically go hand in hand.